# Window[] function in javascript Dev Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm writing a Dashboard Application in C#, using DevExpress components. I am trying to dynamically create a circular gauge, and update the gauges value using a callback function. In the DevExpress sample here:

http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGaugesDemos/Gauges/CircularGauge.aspx

They show how to update a gauge that has already been added to the form at design time. One of the calls in their sample has var gague = window[gaugeName]

When I make the call to this function the value comes back undefiend:

```
function PerformCallbackCore(gaugeName) {

var gauge = window[gaugeName];
m_isDirty = gauge.InCallback();
if (!m_isDirty)
    gauge.PerformCallback();
}
```

Does anyone possibly know why I cannot retrieve the gauge value?

Thanks - Larry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to **bad code** in the gauge demo. Yes, I use (and pay for) DX; I can say that.

The code uses `setTimeout` with a string (enough ick here!) and passes in the "name" of window property assigned to the control with `ClientInstanceName` (the code won't work if the name used and this don't match up). The demo code is further confusing/ugly by having a different "proxy" function for Gauge1 ... GaugeN.

Now, I *suspect* that the `ClientInstanceName` wasn't used or the correct name wasn't passed somewhere, so `window[aPropertyName]` evaluates to undefined, however ..

.. a better way to write it would be to use/pass the object directly instead of relying on the artificial "client name" / window property. See 
[ASPxClientGaugeControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGaugesScriptsASPxClientGaugeControltopic) (and follow links to the [appropriate handler](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxClassesScriptsASPxClientEndCallbackEventHandlertopic)) and consider this:

```
<ClientSideEvents EndCallback="onEndGaugeCallback" />
```

With a single unified callback (and distinct lack of "client names" and useless proxy methods):

```
function onEndGaugeCallback (s, e) {
   // "s" is for Sender; it evaluates to the appropriate [Gauge] control
   // or rename it to "gauge" or whatever :-)
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test this when I get home.